# xcode installs app on iphone but does not run in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Ive added a new device (iPhone 5s) to test my app using xCode 5.0.2. The app installs onto the phone without running in Xcode.

When you select the play button on Xcode, the app builds successfully and installs the app. If you open the app on the iphone it works well - when you close the app on the iPhone, Xcode crashes !!!!

Its kind of working as neat way of getting the app onto a device without load time - but I need to see my logs in Xcode as the app is running on my device.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that you keep the device connected to the computer and thus Xcode while running the app, any NSLog you have or error you get will show up

Comment: the iPhone is still connected to the computer - Ive just tried my old iphone and it runs perfectly well ( app runs on iPhone and Xcode at the same time). I then retried my new iPhone and again it just loads the app only.

Comment: do you mean close the app as in quitting it from multitasking? because then it will cause an error